# Creating identity tables and developing project tables in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, asp.net-identity, connection-string

I followed the tutorial [Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)
and successfully created identity tables for a new project in asp.net web forms.

Now I am confused how can I develop my whole project where my other tables are in SQL Server i.e. I would have another connection string.

For example, for creating identity tables my connecting string is::

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WebFormsIdentity.mdf;Initial Catalog=WebFormsIdentity;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am creating a school management system with the database name `SCHOOL`, so my connection string would be:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source = DESKTOP-055678; Initial Catalog=SCHOOL;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;pooling=false" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So shall I keep these two connection strings or is there any other way?

All of the tutorials in the net only shows creating identity tables but do not show any further steps. Please make me clear, may be I am misunderstanding any concepts. Please clarify it. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest avoid having 2 dbContext. use the ApplicationContextDb for both Identity and your data model

Answer (score 1):

If you have two DBs (and two Connection Strings) then you need to create two `DbContext`s. Something like this.

```
public class FirstDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FirstDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolDbContext()
        : base("MyConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

Another approach is to move all tables (and others) from one DB to another and use single ConnectionString.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. but if you see the tutorial there is no DbContext class, so how can I do that? Another approach you mentioned, how can I transfer the tables from mdf file to SQL Server database? Please help!!!

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Move identity table definitions and data to `school` DB and inherit your `SchoolDbContext` from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: How can I move the identity table definitions and data to `SCHOOL` DB? I searched on net on this topic but can not found any good tutorial.